# What is the difference between a bird?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

Attention here one should not play on words, the question is to understand literally, and there is of course at least one answer.

> What is the difference between a bird?

Comment: This reminds of an old joke that I still don't entirely get: https://parkzer.com/2009/04/17/whats-the-difference-between-a-duck/

Comment: the question is to understand literally, and there is of course at least one answer.

Comment: Dattier, the lateral-thinking tag clashes with literal. I don't want to spar or row.

Comment: A team french have find an answer : https://www.forumfr.com/sujet906849-quelle-diff%C3%A8rence-y-a-t-il-entre-un-oiseau.html?page=2&tab=comments#comment-12335084

Comment: @eyl327 - It's meant to be completely random and nonsensical. That's what's funny. You read the question and start scratching your head - wha? how? who? You can't figure it out. Then you check the answer -- which makes about as much sense as the question.  So, yeah - garbage in, garbage out. No need to think deep. LOL. :)

Comment: Is this a puzzle with an intended solution, or a Zen-koan-like question with no particular answer in mind? "There is of course at least one answer" makes it seem like answers are subjective; subjective questions are not acceptable for this site.

Comment: I don't know why I'm saying this, but is it the word "What"? Because if we remove the question mark, it reads, "What is the difference between a bird"... :)

Answer (score 2):

Tongue-in-cheek answer, because I can't think of any other gimmicks besides the commented link unless we're actually dealing with

> double meanings

The difference between a bird

> and a question mark is that you can question an entire bird but you can only wing a question.